# md-highlight-text for multiple words

Tags: angular-material

I am using `md-highlight-text` to highlight words in a list of checkbox-labels based on search. But I want to highlight multiple words searched.. There is no option/flag for this in the directive?

Code example from md site:

```
<input placeholder="Enter a search term..." ng-model="searchTerm" type="text">
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="result in results" md-highlight-text="searchTerm">
    {{result.text}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

here I want to highlight multiple words typed in the input.

Answer (score 0):

Because I found this in my top search result on the web, and because the question was a bit unclear, I'm going to answer this multiple ways.

Of course, as mentioned in lorenzo montanan's answer, you do need to provide some css for the highlight (I think so, at least).

If the OP (or you, the reader) was asking to highlight multiple words in the results, there is now a md-highlight-flags which could help (see [md-highlight-text documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdHighlightText)) which currently works like this:

> md-highlight-flags - string - A list of flags (loosely based on JavaScript RexExp flags).
>
> Supported flags:
>
> g: Find all matches within the provided text
>
> i: Ignore case when searching for matches
>
> $: Only match if the text ends with the search term
>
> ^: Only match if the text begins with the search term

If, however, you want to type in multiple words in the input and have the output highlight each word separately without having to be in the same order, then md-highlight-text will not, and is not interested in doing that (see: [request for highlighting multiple input words](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/8881) and [another request](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/9282)).  One way to do that is to write your own filter directive.